# how to take the greatest integer and if are 2 or more take one randomly

Tags: java

My code:

```
int zone1;
int zone2;
int zone3;


public void countVotes()
{
if ((zone1 == 0) && (zone2 == 0) && (zone3 == 0))
        {               
            return;
        }
        if ((zone1 == zone2) && (zone2 == zone3))
        {
            newzone = Rnd.get(1, 3);
            return;
        }
        if ((zone2 < zone1) && (zone1 > zone3))
        {
            newzone = 1;
        }
        if ((zone1 < zone2) && (zone2 > zone3))
        {
            newzone = 2;
        }
        if ((zone1 < zone3) && (zone3 > zone2))
        {
            newzone = 3;
        }
        changeZone(newzone);
}
```

and it is not what I exactly want.
How to simply take a greater integer? 
I cannot imagine that I will want add more zones.

Comment: You could do `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(zone1, zone2, zone3))`.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and simple solution would be the following:

```
 int newzone = Math.max(Math.max(zone1, zone2), zone3);
```

As @pbabcdefp suggested

```
int newzone = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(zone1, zone2, zone3));
```

will also work, but these operations require array and list to be created.

Comment: both solution not work for me or maybe i do it wrong

Comment: newzone always = 1, even if zone2 is greater than zone1

Comment: For `int zone1 = 1;
    int zone2 = 2;
    int zone3 = 1;` I get result `2` from both.

Comment: ok i know what i do wrong, if zone1 = 54, zone2 = 34, zone3 = 12, newzone = 1. ;/